# When they form Project D what does the D stands for?

Tags: initial-d

On Initial D at around third to fourth stage, they finally form the group Project D (or get the left members into it) and somewhere along it Ryosuke mentions that "D" also stands for something else that he would reveal when the project is completed.

What does the "D" stand for?

I know it's not "Drifting" (or so I think, since they name it a lot of times with different meaning along the episodes, but I haven't watched it all yet) so I was thinking on something along the lines of "Driver" but wouldn't make much sense I guess.

Comment: I wish I had a better answer for you, as I've seen all of them up through 5th Stage, but drawing a blank right now. I don't think they've came right out and stated it.

Comment: I am half way into fourth season so I have a long way till the end and I have not read the manga which I believe it will be where that goes explained if they explain it as they usually cut a lot of those on anime. ;(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't watched the anime, but I read the manga. What 'D' stands for has not been explained explicity, but in the last chapter, Ryosuke Takahashi mentions three words that start with the letter 'D' when he prays to his girl friend. (mouse over to see the spoiler):

> dream, driver, diamond (in the rough).

Comment: In the anime Ryosuke explicitly says that D stands for dream even though it's right that he speaks about rough diamonds (young talented drivers)

Answer (score 1):

D stands for dreams and also for diamonds.  Project D leader's dream was to train and uncover young, talented drivers and shape them into incredible drivers: like diamonds in the rough.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the straight line in the D is the straightaway and the semicircle is the drift. That's what I always thought. It could represent the repetition of drifting.